# cakephp accessing foreach() at correct level

Tags: cakephp, foreach

I have a multi-dimension foreach() that I cannot seem to access correctly. The first format echoes the correct parent records, but echos only "Array" for the child records. The second format echoes the child records, but gives an error for the parent records. I want to output 4 fields from the parent along with the fields of the corresponding child record.

Take a look at this paste from [Cakebin](http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/73994). It has links to screenshots of the output within it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you need more info, please ask.

Comment: could you paste the error message? Maybe using print_r for each record, to ensure it is an associative array would help you

Comment: if the echo shows up as "Array" it means the value you are attempting to echo is in fact an array.  use `debug($array)` to see its contents

Comment: @pollirrata, there is no error message. Look at the screenshot of the data to see the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the loop with the [pastie](http://pastie.org/3839348) you posted:

```
foreach ($data as $invoice)
{
    debug($invoice['SOP10100']); // should give you all "header" data

    // you should be able to do this:
    foreach ($invoice['SOP10100'] as $headerKey => $headerValue)
    {
        /* snip*/
    }

    foreach ($invoice['InvoiceDetail'] as $invoiceDetail)
    {
        debug($invoiceDetail); // should show entire detail

        // also, this:
        foreach ($invoiceDetail as $detailKey => $detailValue)
        {
            /* snip*/
        }
    }
}
```

You can always use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to make debugging and investigating easier.

Comment: I've been using debug on all the variables. I didn't notice anything wrong with the data. I just don't understand why I either get Array for child records, or error for parent records. It makes no sense.

Comment: @MikeS.: Can you add the output of debug($data) to the paste above? Make sure it's same one which gives you the errors so we can compare the data and the output.

Comment: Ok. With this simple loop http://pastie.org/3839163, I get a sample output like this http://pastie.org/3839156. What I don't understand is that if I echo the output, I get ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray...

Comment: @MikeS.: Your output array doesn't seem very *cakeish*..is it a result of a cake query or a custom one? Can you update the pastie with only `debug($data)` before the loop itself?

Comment: I have no idea how to make my app "cake-ish". I'm learning it as I go. Nonetheless, in this paste, I've added the 2 functions which get the data, then loop through it: http://pastie.org/3839348. Understand, there's a lot more manipulation I need to do in the _prepopulateFields function. But I need to make sure I can access the data first.

Comment: Now I'm getting a clearer picture. In this loop: foreach ($invoices as $fieldName => $fieldValue), I see that $fieldname is SOP10100, and $fieldValue is array of four fields from that table. So, I'm not even reaching SOP10200 (the child table). I need to traverse down to the child table and manipulate those values.

Comment: It took me awhile (OJT is not as fun as it sounds), I finally figured it out. When I ran this debug($invoices['InvoiceDetail'][0]['SOPNUMBE']);, I finally accessed the correct data. Thanks for getting me started down the right path.

Comment: @MikeS.: I've updated the answer, I did the loop in my head so it may not be 100% correct :)

Comment: Ah, crap, you were faster than me.. :)